# How to get mimeType from Cordova File Transfer Plugin?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mime-types, file-transfer, apache-cordova

I am developing hybrid mobile application.

In one of the scenario we need to fetch mimeType from a file when we select or upload a file.

I am using apache FileTransfer.

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI , resolveOnSuccess, resolveOnFail)

Answer (score 5):

you can get it from cordova File plugin.

```
$cordovaFile.checkFile(uri, '')
.then(function(entry) {
    // success
    var name = entry.name;

    entry.file(function(data) {
        // get mime type
        var mime = data.type;
        alert(mime);
    })

}, function(error) {
    // error
    // show toast
});
```

Comment: are you sure this works? I passed in a uri like the following: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A818` and it still returns nothing. I get `FileError` each time.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this in TypeScript and Angular 2:

```
this._File.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(somefileUri).then((entry: Entry) => {
    if (entry) {
        var fileEntry = entry as FileEntry;
        fileEntry.file(success => { 
            var mimeType = success.type;
        }, error => {
            // no mime type found;
        });        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`file-transfer` does not expose mimeType and other FileUploadOptions params.

Mimetype autodetection is only supported for uploads in [Windows plugin code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/182b0c5ebebd8c0d313c676de0f92b8a56a81cb1/src/windows/FileTransferProxy.js#L331-L335).

And [here is a Jira ticket for this feature CB-5946](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5946) - it also has some suggestions on Android implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2 I use this:

```
export class Plugins {

albums = {
    open () : Promise<any>  {
        return ImagePicker.getPictures({
                quality: 100,
                maximumImagesCount: 1,
        }).then((imgUrls) => {
            return imgUrls;
        }, (err) => {
            if(err.error == "cordova_not_available") {
                alert("Cordova is not available, please make sure you have your app deployed on a simulator or device");
            } else {
                console.log("Failed to open albums: " + err.error);
            }
        });
    },
}
```

...

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  directives: [UploadButton]
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

openAlbums = (): void => {
var $self = this;
this._plugins.albums.open().then((imgUrls) => {
  imgUrls.forEach((imageUrl: string): void => {
    if (imageUrl) {
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageUrl, function (entry: FileEntry) {
        entry.file(file=> {
          console.log('mimeType', file.type);
        }, ((error:FileError) => console.log(error)));
      });
    }
  });
});  };
```

`resolveLocalFileSystemURL` gives back through the success callback an `Entry` which I had to cast to `FileEntry` to get access to the file method which gives back a `File` which extends `Blob` that has the mime type property.

Comment: With the latest version Ionic and the Cordova the File type doesn't have a type parameter.